# What is a hostname to use in UNC paths that refers to current machine in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, localhost, unc

What is a hostname to use in UNC paths that refers to the current machine in XP?

> eg. `\\localhost\share\file.txt`

Except that `localhost` doesn't work.  What will work?

Comment: What application is your question for? A batch file?  A script?  Maybe we can help you out better with some more information?

Comment: It is in an `.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

use the actual `computername` or `\\127.0.0.1\share\file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

`COMPUTERNAME` is an environment variable that has the local computer's hostname.  So `\\%COMPUTERNAME%\Share` will work provided the process is running on the local computer.

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't think UNC paths can expand out environment variables like `%COMPUTERNAME%`.

Comment: @CJ7 Ah, it works in Windows 7.  I assumed it did in XP, too.  Sorry about that.